# Can you wrap Python Over a Fortran Code directly?

Tags: python, fortran, wrapper

I tried searching for this, but can't seem to find a read that answers my question.

Basically, I want to know if I can wrap Python over a Fortran Code directly, or do I have to go through C/C++, i.e., I'd have to wrap the Fortran code with C/C++, and then wrap Python over the C/C++ code?

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap Python over a Fortran Code"? Can you give an example?

Comment: The question is off topic on SO, but have a look at https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyfortran/

Comment: @FredLarson Basically, I want to write a Python script that interfaces directly with a Fortran code. The Fortran code should output certain variables (usually arrays) directly to a Python data type using the script, so that I can do operations on the outputted data in Python.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks. I will take a look. But isn't creating wrappers/interfaces relevant on SO?

Comment: You are asking for a recommendation of a third-party tool or library, which is off topic. On SO, you have to post your code and ask specific code-related questions.

Comment: We have a whole tag [tag:f2py] for f2py. Many questions tagged both Fortran and Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran+python will have it. Many others will show the use of [tag:ctypes]. It seems unlikely to me you could miss any of these if you tried to search the internet, or indeed Stack Overflow, for a few minutes.

Comment: I did see some of those. But all of those seemed to involve C/C++ in the middle. My question was if you go directly from Python to Fortran with C/C++?

Comment: You can have a python script to access a library writen in Fortran and call its routines directly without any tool, I've done it, **if** you respect the function/subroutine signatures, calling convention, with involves a series of non-trivial subtleties relating to name-aliasing, type/kind/rank equivalence, string termination, hidden arguments, array storage order, pointer representation and (God, have mercy) stuff related to derived types, like padding, sequence... tl;dr do yourself a favor and use a tool, like f2py

Comment: F2py does use some C/C++ wrappers, but *you* do not have to go through them, the are created automatically. You were asking *"do I have to go through C/C++, i.e., I'd have to wrap the Fortran code with C/C++, and then wrap Python over the C/C++ code?"* and the answer is NO, you do NOT have to do that with f2py.

Comment: @VladimirF only C or both C and C++? I doubt if C++ would be needed.

Comment: @King I was quoting the OP and I meant or. You do not need to write any of these.